# Error while parsing NSMutablearray values

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `NSMuttableArray`which contains the structure like below,

```
28 =     (
    twenty
);
30 =     (
    thirty
);
32 =     (
    thirty
);
```

I am trying to store the values like `28,30,32` into a separate array. I tried loop as,

```
NSMutableArray *getvalueshere;
for(int i=0;i<getvalueshere.count;i++)
   NSArray *getval = [getvalueshere objectAtindex:i];
}
```

On trying this, my app gets crash saying `__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`.

Comment: As the others are telling you, you are showing data that is consistent with a dictionary, not an array. The variable may be of type `NSMutableArray`, but it contains a dictionary, not an array.

Comment: @DuncanC If its a dictionary, I tired with @vadian code and shows me `No visible @interface for 'NSMutableArray' declares the selector 'allKeys'`. I hope this clears its not a dictionary

Comment: One does not parse an array, it is just accessed, there is a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object is a NSDictionary as the error message reveals.
You can get the numbers – which are actually the keys of the dictionary – with

```
NSArray *getval = [getvalueshere allKeys];
```

Comment: I tried with your code it says `No visible @interface for 'NSMutableArray' declares the selector 'allKeys'`

Comment: declare the variable as NSDictionary. The content is doubtless a dictionary

Comment: Changed into NSDictionary as you said, but the order varies, How can i get the same order.

Comment: dictionaries are unordered by definition. If you want a specific order, sort the resulting array.

Answer (score 0):

It's saying getvalueshere is an NSDictionary which doesn't recognize objectAtIndex.  When you declared getvalueshere, you gave it a NSDictionary like structure.  It is considered an NSDictionary even though you explicitly stated it should be an NSMutableArray.

Comment: I am sure its a `NSMutableArray`. I had given in .h as `@property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *getvalueshere;`

Comment: This should be a comment, it does not provide an answer to the question.